# Programming language popularity: Is there data on migration trends?

Tags: programming-languages, research, migration

I'm looking for historical statistics showing approximately how many developers of some language X switch to language Y. It should be the kind of data that answers question such as:

- Are former VB6 developers using mainly C# or VB.NET now?
- Have many Java developers switched their main development language to Scala so far?
- etc.

I'm not doing a study, I'm mainly curious. Is there some website or institution that collects and publishes such data?

Comment: I agree this isn't an easy job. Maybe you should conduct a survey but the sample size should be big enough to show the overall picture.

Comment: the trouble there is it will be very hard to eliminate selection bias i.e. a survey about switching to scala will probably disproportionally attract scala enthusiasts

Comment: @jk. ... and also attract Java enthusiasts who think that Scala is a massive affront to the original goals and intentions of the Java language. *cough*

Answer (score 6):

Well, there's popularity stats [here](http://langpop.com/) and especially [here - with deltas](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html) but I don't know of anything measuring who's moving to what.  It would be interesting to plot but I'm not sure if it would be an easy thing to capture.

Comment: Probably good for overall popularity, but what would be more relevant would be figures for usage and movement within domains.

Comment: even for that you have to bear in mind that in absolute terms probably every language is increasing, tiobe and langpop show relative trends (if anything)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that "migrated from" is even an easily defined metric, let alone easily measured.  For example, I learned python last year for internal-use scripting, but our product is still written in C++.  You could say I migrated from C++, but python really replaced perl for me, which I gave up because none of my colleagues knows it anymore.  I've done projects in Java and php in the last year as well, but I wouldn't say I "migrated to" those either, both of which were "day job" languages for me in the late 90s.

In other words, measuring migration assumes almost everyone is a monoglot, which isn't a valid assumption.

Answer (score 0):

[ohloh.net](https://www.ohloh.net/languages?query=&sort=code) collects information on open-source projects. It counts things like total number of lines committed for each language - number of contributors making commits for each language etc. It can be interesting to see the trends. For example, the number of contributors making commits of C code is seeing a small lift since 2010, although the total number of commits is still falling sharply. This would indicate that more people are committing C code, but in larger chunks. It's not possible from these stats to say where those extra contributors may have migrated from though..